# Error in upsampling layer of Sequential model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand how the `Upsampling2D` layer works in `keras` so I made a single layer `Sequential` model.

`trial = Sequential()
trial.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2) , input_shape = (100,100,1)))`

The input is a random array :
`x = random.normal(0 , 1 , size = (100,100,1))`

The interpreter reports the following error :
`ValueError: Error when checking : expected up_sampling2d_7_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 100, 1)`

I am just trying to upsample an image using the upsampling layer. How do I fix the error ? Or is there some other way to achieve the same thing ?

Using `keras` with `TensorFlow` backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Keras` processes data by batches. By default, the first dimension is the batch size. In this case, batch is the number of images you want to upsample. If you only want to upsample a single image, define your input as such:

```
x = random.normal(0 , 1 , size = (1, 100,100,1))
```

and it should work.

Here is a working example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

trial = Sequential()
trial.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2,2), input_shape=(100,100,1))

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1,100,100,1))
x_up = trial.predict(x)

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(x[0 , : , : , 0])
ax[1].imshow(x_up[0 , : , : , 0])
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. But how do I plot it using `matplotlib.pyplot` it is reporting an error saying `invalid input dimensions for image` since the dimensions are `(1,200,200,1)`

Comment: Also can you please upvote the question i rarely get upvotes on my questions :/

Comment: The plot portion of the code still reports the same error as before.

Comment: Changing it to this `ax[0].imshow(x[0 , : , : , 0])
ax[1].imshow(new[0 , : , : , 0])` fixed it

Comment: Oh, yes it is true, i will fix it. Since this is one channel image, it must be plotted as 2D. if it were RGB/A image it would have been ok to keep the last dimension.